# List of subset sums Prolog

Tags: prolog, sum, subset

Given a list `L` of natural numbers I need to create a list containing the sums of the elements of all the subsets of `L`. For example if `L=[1,3,6]` I want to obtain the list `[0,1,3,4,6,7,9,10]`.

I tried to use this code

```
subsetSums(List,Sums) :- findall(Sum,(subset(Sub,List),sum_list(Sub,Sum)),Sums).
```

but with the following query I get `[0]` as the only result instead of `[0,1,2,3]`

```
?- subsetSums([1,2],Sums).
```

Where am I wrong?

EDIT: I'm working on SWI Prolog and `subset/2` should be a native predicate.

Comment: Where is `subset/2` defined? Is it really `subset(Subset, List)` or should it be `subset(List, Subset)`?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't specified that I'm working on SWI Prolog and it should be subset(Subset,List) according to the documentation http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=subset/2

Comment: It doesn't work even changing the code to `subsetSums(List,Sums) :- findall(Sum,(list_to_set(List,Set),subset(Sub,Set),sum_list(Sub,Sum)),Sums).`

Comment: [`subset/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=subset/2) only checks the property. Both params are input (`+`).

Comment: Even if `subset/2` did what you wanted, `sum_list/2` does not work on sets. Just write your own `list_subset/2` predicate. It's easy. Or at least you can find it half a dozen places here on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in the comment, you have to write your own `subset/2` predicate and then use `findall/3` on this predicate, like this:

```
subset([], []).
subset([E|T], [E|T1]):-
  subset(T, T1).
subset([_|T], L):-
  subset(T, L).

subsetSums(List,Sums) :- 
    findall(S,(subset(List,Sub),sumlist(Sub,S)),Sums).

?- subsetSums([1,2],L).
L = [3, 1, 2, 0]
?- subsetSums([1,2,3],L).
L = [6, 3, 4, 1, 5, 2, 3, 0]
```

where the output of `subset/2` is:

```
subset([1,2,3],L).
L = [1, 2, 3]
L = [1, 2]
L = [1, 3]
L = [1]
L = [2, 3]
L = [2]
L = [3]
L = []
```